# Capacitor for 12v door intercom

Tags: voltage, capacitor

Please forgive me, I have extremely limited knowledge of EE.

I have a 12 volt door intercom system that I am happy with except it turns out that I hooked up the electric door strike directly to the monitor and sometimes the door strike won't energize correctly because I assume the power supply can't handle it.

I purchased a timer relay and a power supply to replace the direct connection to the intercom, but turns out that it is not easy to snake the new wires I would need through the wall and I would like to avoid opening up my walls to run a few new wires.

Is it possible to add a capacitor into the system that would help energize the door strike (5 seconds)?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, but more information is needed.  Photos of the pc board/electronics, icom make and model, purchased power supply, etc.

Comment: actually a capacitor would make it worse, competing for power with the coil. You would be better off reducing the friction and thus energy needed to actuate using oil, tightening hinges, filing rubbing bolt receivers down, shimming out any crookedness, etc. You shouldn't need access to the wires to replace the power supply though, it replaces the old one, right?

Answer (score 0):

the door strike will typically have its own power supply separate from the intercom.

If the relay is not activating for long enough a time delay relay can be added.

somethign like "K-80 powersupply control" combinwes power supoply and delay relay in one package.